# Running Hyperledger-Fabric containers as non-root user

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Currently, whenever any of the core Hyperledger Fabric containers (Peer, Orderer) are deployed, they run with root privileges.

I already found that instantiation of chaincode requires root privileges and this problem has not been addressed yet: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-9394?jql=text%20~%20%22non-root%22

I also tried to run HLF containers with non-root user by setting the "user" environmental variable in docker-compose and point it to the UID/GID of the host user. This obviously resulted with a failure.

Has anyone managed to successfully deploy Hyperledger Fabric with non-root privileges?

Comment: What was your failure?  We've run the peer and orderer as non-root successfully

Comment: Orderer and Peer containers immediately failed after launch due to no write access to /var/ folder to which they wanted to write files and logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, both peers and orderers store / write their ledger files to `/var/hyperledger/production`.  In general, you should be mounting an external volume using that as the mount point.  If you are running as a non-root user, you'll need to make sure that user has permissions on the host directory you are mounting.

Answer (score 0):

Running Hyperledger-Fabric containers as non-root user

Is this fixed ? can any one please confirm